# Change disconnect/terminate setting for Pycharm when closing debug or run tab

Tags: python, pycharm

Previously I selected the "disconnect" option, with the "Remember, don't ask again" box ticked, from this popup (which Pycharm displays every time when you close a tab with a running process in it, until you tick the remember box).

[image]

This means if I close the tab on a long running process (instead of first stopping it then closing it) it runs in the background consuming resources.

I would like to know if it's possible to change the value of this option? I cannot find it anywhere in settings, or run configuration.

I'm running Pycharm Professional 2018.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to go `Appearance & Behavior`, submenu `System settings`:
[image: system settings]

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, I think it might be a bit bugged, as I did check this setting (it was on "ask") but there were no new dialog boxes shown. Changing it to terminate worked however. Changing it back to ask also does not seem to do anything to fix the issue.