# How to preserve a running command in the PyCharm terminal while shutting off PyCharm

Tags: bash, terminal, process, pycharm

How do you exit PyCharm and at the same time preserve a process that is running in a PyCharm terminal.

Background: I would like to restart PyCharm to make use of an updated plugin. However, I also have an important command running that has been processing data for a long time. I really don't want to kill this command:

[image: Assume some important code is running in this PyCharm terminal]

Is it possible to transfer this process to another terminal? (e.g. tmux).

Note: I'm using `bash` inside the PyCharm terminal, and I'm on a Windows machine (however, UNIX answers are definitely appreciated too).

I've looked in the PyCharm documentation, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Depends on your shell. But if you use linux, you can run the process in the background by using the character & at the end of the line

`$ htop &` will open htop as background process freeing the terminal or console you use to make the call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change disconnect/terminate setting for Pycharm when closing debug or run tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128245/change-disconnect-terminate-setting-for-pycharm-when-closing-debug-or-run-tab)

Comment: Thanks @AndreVale69 for your suggestion. How sure are you that this `disconnect` option will keep the command running? That link answers how to toggle between disconnect and terminate; It doesn't state if the command is unharmed between reboots.

Comment: @melvio Yes, I'm trying it now with my private project. Pycharm will ask you if you want to kill/disconnect the process when you leave the Pycharm window. Try to believe.

Comment: @melvio I leave here the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/system-settings.html),
**item**: _When closing a tool window with a running process_

Comment: Since you're using Windows [if you carefully check the system manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642382) you'll notice that what PyCharm is doing when it launches the terminal is more complex than what we might expect when launching a native Linux terminal. I'd honestly recommend you either let the terminal finish or launch whatever process you're running from a terminal external to PyCharm next time. It's just simpler because the owning process of the terminal is PyCharm itself in your case.

Comment: For the other people reading, watch out! `disconnect` does nothing with processes running in a terminal! I tried it myself on another machine. 
The `disconnect` option indeed does pop up when you are running your application code (e.g. code run as described here: [jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-applications.html](https://jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-applications.html)). 
However, I lost my terminal activity between reboots!

Comment: Here is a process for Linux OS, I am not sure if this will work on Windows OS or not, but should work on Pycharm terminal.
You can use 'ctrl + z' to suspend the running process and get your terminal back, this will not stop or kill your running process, then use 'bg' comamnd to send the process to background. Now you can close your terminal and you can open duplicate terminal and confirm the process is still running. The process will not be killed and it will run until its finished.